# Could not find Developer Disk Image Xcode Issue with iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to run an app I made in Xcode on my iPhone, but when I try to run it I get the error saying:

```
Could not find Developer Disk Image
```

I have Xcode version 7.2.1 and iPhone version 9.3.1. Why is this issue happening and what do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: Is your phone added to a developer account?

Answer (score 1):

your xcode 7.2.1 has max ios sdk support for ios 9.2.1 sdk i.e iphone running ios 9.2.1 or below...download xcode 7.3.1 and it will not give this error...hope it helps :)